# How to show/edit custom properties on the properties page in AEM

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

I have several assets under `/content/dam/myassets` in AEM 6

I've given a custom property to each of these assets with the name of `dc:location`.

Is there a way that I can show this property on the asset's properties page so that users can see and edit it? This is how the property page looks at the moment.

[image]

**What I've tried**

I've added `loc` property under `/apps/dam/content` (shown below) but still I can't see it on the properties page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a GUI for modifying the Asset Metadata forms. To get there, select Tools > Assets > Metadata Schemas from the left rail. Documentation can be found at http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/content/assets/metadata-schemas.html.